# Error:The import org.apache cannot be resolved even after adding jars

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop, mapreduce

Before running the driver class of mapreduce program its showing as
`The import org.apache cannot be resolved`

I have added dependencies in `pom.xml`.
I am using `hadoop 2.6.0` and `eclipse luna` working on `ubuntu 14.04 LTS`. My `pom.xml` file looks like as:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
<version>2.6.0</version>
<name>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</name>


<properties><!-- Needed for generating FindBugs warnings using parent pom -->
    <mr.basedir>${project.parent.basedir}/..</mr.basedir>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
******************
</build>
```

please help me how to solve this issue!

Comment: @alvitis Hi Can you help me in this ?

Comment: Will be easier if you show the class having the issue.

Comment: @Tome its basically a driver class in the declaration part